# Python: Easiest way to break a Socket Pipe Connection for Testing Purposes?

Tags: python, sockets, connection, pipe

I'm testing responses for BrokenPipeError between a server application and a client application. I'm working on responses from the server to handle the BrokenPipeError appropriately. What would be the easiest way to break the connection (from the client side) in order to reproduce this error?

I am using standard python sockets as the connection.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: just exit the client while connected.

The simplest way I can see to break the connection from the client is to just close the client while you have a connection.

I quickly coded this example of a simple server-client in Python to demonstrate:

server.py:

```
import socket

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

serverSocket.bind(("192.168.1.111", 6969))

serverSocket.listen(1)

conn, addr = serverSocket.accept()

while True:
    print(conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
    conn.send("Response".encode("utf-8"))
```

client.py:

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect(("192.168.1.111", 6969))

while True:
    data_out = input("> ").encode("utf-8")

    if len(data_out) > 0:
        clientSocket.send(data_out)

    print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
```

This will let the client send some text and receive "Response" from the server, which it prints. The server will print whatever it receives and send back "Response". Simple.

All I had to do was exit the client.py while there was an active connetion and the server gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn.send("Response".encode("utf-8"))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

There's your broken pipe.

Comment: how to not get the broken pipe error?